# How to Calculate a Weekending Date, if the inputs are a date and a weekending day(sun,mon,tue,wed,thu, fri or sat)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, weekend

If the inputs are a date and the week ending day(In some businesses weekending day will a Fri(6), Saturday(7) or a Sunday(1)), then how would one calculate the weekending date for a particular date.
For example

```
f('9/2/2016',6) = '9/2/2016' -- Weekending day a Friday
f('9/2/2016',7)='9/3/2016' -- weekending day a Saturday
f('9/2/2016',1)='9/4/2016' -- weekending day a Sunday
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the SQL code that solves the problem:

```
declare @tdate datetime
declare @weekendingday int
set @weekendingday=7  --weekending saturday
set @tdate='2016-09-02'
select DATEADD (D, case when @weekendingday - DatePart (DW, @TDate) < 0 then 7+(@weekendingday - DatePart (DW, @TDate)) else @weekendingday - DatePart (DW, @TDate) end , @TDate)
```